# Directivity Pattern of microphone array

Tags: beamforming

Directivity pattern of a microphone array is fourier transfrom of  microphone weight values. By modifying the amplitude weights, we can modify the shape of the directivity pattern.

I can really see this when all microphone weights are equally valued.
Fourier transform of a rectangle is a sinc func like picture below:

[image: Equally valued microphone array elements and directivity pattern]

Now I believe if I apply a sinc function for my microphone array's element values I should get a rectangular shape in my directivity pattern.

I have a simulation program of my own. Which works when microphone values are equally valued . But I am not getting what I expect(a rectangular pattern) when I give sinc values to microphone array elements.

Am I missing something teorically or it is just my program bugged?

Edit: As requested in comments, weights that I apply can be seen in the graph below. 40 is the microphone count of my array. Sorry for disgusting looking graph it is the output of my C++ program.

[image]

Comment: Can you show what `sinc` weightings you are using? Your reasoning seems sound.

Comment: @PeterK. I added, it is my own C++ program sorry if it does not looks well

Comment: remember sinc has an infinite tail, so unless you have infinite microphones, you have to truncate it and the response will not be a perfect rectangle.  windowing is probably better than truncation.

Comment: You're using the *magnitude* of a sinc function, not the sinc function itself (which is bipolar). This and the effect of truncating the infinitely long sinc sequence result in the effects you see.

Comment: @endolith I am really not expecting a perfect rectangle , something like rectangle will make me happy. I don't care ripples or transaction band for now .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I said in the comment, you sound like you are doing things correctly.

Below are two plots generated by the `scilab`code at the end.

The first plot shows two different weightings applied to the sensors.  The second plot shows the associated beam patterns.  While the $\tt sinc$ one is not "uniform" it is a fair approximation.

[image: Sensor weightings]

[image: Associated beam patterns]

**EDIT**

Changing the code below to cater for an even number of sensors:

```
NOn2 = 20;
N = 2*NOn2;
w_uniform = ones(1,N);
omega = 2*%pi*([0:N-1] - N/2)/N + 0.0001;
w_sinc = [sin(N/15*omega)./(omega) ]
```

Then I get the plots below.

[image]

[image]

The relationship between the weights and the beam pattern is like a Fourier transform:  the broader the `sinc`, the narrower the beam pattern. The narrower the `sinc`, the wider the beam pattern.

---

CODE ONLY BELOW

```
// http://www.astron.nl/other/workshop/MCCT/MondayPatel.pdf
lambda = 1;
d = lambda/3;
theta = [-%pi/2:0.01:%pi/2];

phase_adjacent = 2*%pi*d/lambda*sin(theta);

NOn2 = 7;
N = 2*NOn2 + 1;
w_uniform = ones(1,N);
omega = 2*%pi*[-NOn2:NOn2]/N + 0.0001;
w_sinc = [sin(N/4*omega)./(omega) ]

e_to_phi = exp(-%i*phase_adjacent.'*[0:N-1]);

r_uniform = e_to_phi*w_uniform';
r_sinc = e_to_phi*w_sinc';

figure(0);
clf;
plot(theta/%pi*180,abs(r_uniform));
plot(theta/%pi*180,abs(r_sinc),'r.');
title('Uniform weighted (blue solid) and sinc weighted (red dotted) array resposnes');

figure(1);
clf;
plot(w_uniform);
plot(w_sinc,'r.');
title('Uniform weighted (blue solid) and sinc weighted (red dotted) sensor weightings');
```

Comment: I am sorry that I suck in this subject and thanks and upvote for your great answer. I understand you have 40 tap uniform and sinc weighted taps. And e_to_phi is like sound source(I hope) recieved with a delay in taps. I can't where you are summing the tap amplitudes. Can I ask you that?

Comment: The line `r_uniform = e_to_phi*w_uniform';` calculates $\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} w_n e^{i2*\pi\frac{d}{\lambda}\sin(\theta) n}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your answers really helps me. I wish I could do more than upvote sometimes.